# Aggregate if string contains specific text in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I've seen a lot of posts on this topic so apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't figure out my problem.

I have

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('bike+ride','shoe+store','ride','mountian%20bike','ride+along'),
             count = c(2,5,8,7,6))
```

and want to sum each `count` if it `name` contains a string `group`

```
group <- data.frame(group = c('ride','bike'))
```

So the end result looks as follows:

```
Group   Count
bike      9
ride     16
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R idea,

```
sapply(sapply(as.character(group$group), function(i) grep(i, df$name)), function(i) sum(df$count[i]))


#or make it a function

aggr1 <- function(var1, grp, cnt){
  m1 <- sapply(as.character(grp), function(i) grep(i, var1))
  final_d <- sapply(m1, function(i) sum(cnt[i]))
  return(data.frame(Group = names(final_d), 
                    Count = as.integer(final_d), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
         )
}

aggr1(df$name, group$group, df$count)

#  Group Count
#1  ride    16
#2  bike     9
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Any idea how I would handle instances where the name includes characters sich as `+` or `%20`?

Comment: In your example you do have those characters in the name and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(group$group, FUN = function(x, df) {
  out <- df[grepl(pattern = x, x = df$name), ]
  data.frame(group = x, count = sum(out$count))
}, df = df, simplify = FALSE))

  group count
1  ride    16
2  bike     9
```

In two steps:

```
# make a data.frame which locates where each group level is located
grp <- as.data.frame(sapply(group$group, FUN = function(x) grepl(pattern = x, x = df$name)))
names(grp) <- group$group

# based on above location (TRUE/FALSE), sum accordingly
data.frame(count = apply(grp, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x, df) {
  sum(df[x, "count"])
}, df = df))

     count
ride    16
bike     9
```

Comment: Some speed improvements, if I may?  `data.frame(group = group, count = sapply(group$group, FUN = function(x) sum(df[grepl(pattern = x, x = df$name, fixed = TRUE), "count"])))` (no need in `do.call` or creating a `data.frame` within each iteration, adding `fixed = TRUE`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A way using `tidyverse` packages `purrr`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr, purr and tidyr

groups <- c('ride','bike')

map_df(groups, ~setNames(summarize_(df, interp(~sum(df$count[grepl(var, name)], na.rm = TRUE), var = .x)), .x)) %>% 
      gather(group, count, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: This seems quite pedestrian when it comes to including extra `group$group` levels.

Comment: I agree. Modified the answer to including extra levels.