# How do I sum rows containing a certain (unknown) text in r?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have a table looking like this:

| row | String | Number | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | W123ABC-1 | 9 | F1 |
| 2 | W123ABC | 4 | F1 |
| 3 | W123ABC-3; W123ABC-1; W123ABC | 11 | F2 |
| 4 | S678DEF-2; S678DEF-3 | 3 | F3 |
| 5 | D345GHI | 4 | F1 |
| 6 | D345GHI-5; D345GHI-8 | 7 | F1 |
| 7 | S678DEF; S678DEF-3; S678DEF-6 | 12 | F3 |
| 8 | S678DEF-4 | 1 | F2 |

I would like to sum the values in the **Number** column of all rows containing the same first 7 symbols in the **String** column for each value in the **File** column.

**Example** string "D345GHI":

- Exists in row 5 and 6
- Has values 4 in F1 and 7 in F1

*Result:*

- Sum of values for F1 = 11

**Example** string "W123ABC":

- Exists in row 1,2 and 3
- Has values 9 in F1, 4 in F1 and 11 in F2

*Result:*

- Sum of values for F1 = 13
- Sum of values for F2 = 11

**Example** string "S678DEF":

- Exists in row 4,7 and 8
- Has values 3 in F3, 12 in F3 and 1 in F2

*Result:*

- Sum of values for F2 = 1
- Sum of values for F3 = 15

---

All symbols in the **String** column after position 7 are irrelevant.

I have read a quite similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208119/aggregate-if-string-contains-specific-text-in-r). The difference is that I don't know the exact texts I am looking for (I don't know all the names in the **String** column). All I know is that for it's **Number** value to be summed, the first 7 symbols of the string must be the same.

Anyone knows how to do this using r?

Comment: Do it in two steps:  first, compute the string you are using to compare (which I think is the first 7 characters of the `String` column).  Then use a summary function to summarize over all unique values of that column and `File`.  There are several ways to do each of these things; the base R way is to use `substr()` and `tapply()`, but there are also `tidyverse` and `data.table` ways.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  An approach would be to take all the contents of the "String" column, separate all the values at commas, extract the leftmost seven digits of each and use `unique()` to get a list of unique string-starters.  From there you could work out a filtering+summing method and use `lapply()` or a variant to apply it to the string starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `data.table` approach

*functionality*

- group by substring of the first 7 characters from `String`: `(substr(String, 1, 7)` and by `File`
- calculate the `sum` of the `Number` colum for each group

*code*

```
library(data.table)
# if not already data.table, uncomment following line
#  setDT(mydata)
mydata[, .(total = sum(Number)), keyby = .(subString = substr(String, 1, 7), File)]
#    subString   File total
#       <char> <char> <int>
# 1:   D345GHI     F1    11
# 2:   S678DEF     F2     1
# 3:   S678DEF     F3    15
# 4:   W123ABC     F1    13
# 5:   W123ABC     F2    11
```

*sample data*

```
mydata <- data.table::fread(text = "row     String  Number  File
1   W123ABC-1   9   F1
2   W123ABC     4   F1
3   W123ABC-3; W123ABC-1; W123ABC   11  F2
4   S678DEF-2; S678DEF-3    3   F3
5   D345GHI     4   F1
6   D345GHI-5; D345GHI-8    7   F1
7   S678DEF; S678DEF-3; S678DEF-6   12  F3
8   S678DEF-4   1   F2", header = TRUE)
```

the `tidyverse` way

```
# make sure mydata is a data.frame or tibble

library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  group_by(subString = substr(String, 1, 7), File) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Number))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   subString [3]
#   subString File  total
#   <chr>     <chr> <int>
# 1 D345GHI   F1       11
# 2 S678DEF   F2        1
# 3 S678DEF   F3       15
# 4 W123ABC   F1       13
# 5 W123ABC   F2       11
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with DT - does this discard all "String" entries other than the first on each row?  From the OPs sample data that wouldn't make a difference as each row has only one pattern, but I can't tell from the OP whether it's a safe assumption or not.

Comment: correct.. Is sees all string values as is and only lookas at the first 7 characters from each row of  `String` for grouping.... The OP did not specify he wanted to 'split' these rows. Looking at his desired output, it seems the splitting is not desired.

Comment: @Wimpel you are correct, splitting the rows is not desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

**EDITED**:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # remove substring suffixes by extracting all caps:
  mutate(String = str_extract_all(String, "[A-Z]+")) %>%
  # pivot list longer:
  unnest(String) %>%
  # for each combination of `File` and `String`...
  group_by(File, String) %>%
  #... compute the sum of `Number`:
  summarise(N = sum(Number))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   File [2]
  File  String     N
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 F1    A         14
2 F1    B         14
3 F1    C          5
4 F1    CCCCC      7
5 F2    D         11
```

**EDIT 2**:
if removing the suffixes is not possible, for whatever reason, and the defining criterion must be a certain number of characters, like 7, then the `mutate` operation can be adapted like this:

```
mutate(String = str_extract_all(String, "(?<=^|;\\s).{7}"))
```

Here, we use positive look-behind (`(?<=...)`) to extract only on the condition that the 7 chars be preceded (i) by the start of the string (`^`) or (`|`) (ii) by `;` followed by whitespace `\\s`

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  String = c("A-5; B-1; C", "CCCCC-1", "B-1; A", "D"),
  Number = c(5,7,9,11),
  File = c("F1", "F1","F1","F2")
)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but misses one element of the OP - the 'strings' are defined by the first seven characters (i.e. `W123ABC-3`, `W123ABC-1`, `W123ABC` should all be summed under `W123ABC`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Have adapted solution now.